# How to configure gMSA in docker container for user authentication

Tags: windows, docker, active-directory

I Have docker hosted in a win2K16 server (in the test scenario the host itself is a Domain Controller but in the real case scenario the host will be a machine in the domain).

In the container I have a IIS site that is required to do authentication through AD.

I have created a gMSA following the instructions in this [url](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2012/12/16/windows-server-2012-group-managed-service-accounts/) and tried to configure the host and the container using this [steps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/containerstuff/2017/01/30/create-a-container-with-active-directory-support/)

I start the container using the command: `docker run -d --security-opt "credentialspec=file://gmsa.json" -h gmsa  <image-name>` (I've tried with and without the `-h` parameter) and loggin in with `docker exec -ti <container-id> cmd`.

In the host the command `nltest /parentdomain` returns as expected but `nltest /query` always return:

> Flags: 0
>
> Connection Status = 1786 0x6fa ERROR_NO_TRUST_LSA_SECRET

Can anyone point me out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that you cannot use host the container in the Domain Controller because you can't add the DC computer to the gMSA group.

Comment: Can you clarify a little? Do you mean that you cannot use the container host machine itself as a Domain Controller? I am struggling with the same setup, trying to create a Proof of concept much like you where I only have one machine acting as Domain controller and container host. Did you get it to work once you used a separate machine as Domain controller? No other further actions?